# mysql_query to PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following code in the old "mysql_query"

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT defe FROM information WHERE term = 1");
$fetch = $db->fetch_array($query);
print_r($fetch);
```

I want to transform this to the PDO way of retrieving information from database. I tried the following (did not work- does not display any result) :

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT defe FROM information WHERE term = 1');
$fetch = $query->fetch();
print_r($fetch);
```

the connection to the database is established and it stored in the `$db` variable (only the PDO).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) the query

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT defe FROM information WHERE term = 1');
$query->execute();
$fetch = $query->fetch();
print_r($fetch);
```

You can also use [`PDO::query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) since you aren't using any parameters in your query

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT defe FROM information WHERE term = 1');
$fetch = $query->fetch();
print_r($fetch);
```

Comment: or use `$db->query()` instead. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php (I'm not advocating unescaped values, but he isn't using any variables here)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT defe FROM information WHERE term = 1');  
$result = $query->fetch();  
print_r($result);
```

But if you want to prepare it (may be for security reasons) , you need to execute it.

So it would be

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT defe FROM information WHERE term = 1');  
$query->execute();  
$result = $query->fetch();  
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I am a beginner in this PDO thingy.. I do not know what prepare does .. I copied the code from somewhere else and started working on it :( That is how I learn lol

Comment: then you better learn about prepare ....http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php .... because they are very useful

Comment: @shnisaka: "prepare" essentially sends the the query to the MySQL server which then compiles it (prepares it for execution). "execute" is what actually causes it to run and fetch the data and return it to your PHP script. Furthermore, you can put variables in your prepared query (using `?` or `:myvar`) which then you can then substitute by passing an [associative] array to the `execute` method. This is the preferred way of doing things as it's both safe, and fast (particularly when running the same query multiple times).